# Whats the partial fraction for $f(x) = (-2s^2 -1)/(s^2(s^2+2))$

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Im trying to find the answer for the following inverse laplace, but when doing that $A/s$ + $B/s^2$ + $(Cs+D)/(s^2+2)$ , Im finding that b = -1/2 ; d= -3/2 but a and c are undefinied.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and re-fromat your question accordingly.

Comment: Why do you say $A$ and $C$ are undefined? Do you instead mean they are equal to $0$?

Comment: @JorgeLucasPereiraCohen: I get $$\dfrac{-2 s^2-1}{s^2 \left(s^2+2\right)} = -\dfrac{3}{2 \left(s^2+2\right)}-\dfrac{1}{2 s^2}$$ It is easy to verify the RHS result, just combine them back up. Why do you think your result is wrong?

Comment: Could you show the work that you did to reach your conclusion. I am also confused how you got $A$ and $C$ undefined.

Comment: Like, by making that $-2s^2-1 = 2A/s  + B/s^2 + (Cs+D)/(s^2+2)$. I found first that B=-1/2, then that D=-3/2 but when I tried to find A and C values it comes that -3=3a+c and -3=-3a-c . Finding that are a infinite number of solutions @Moo

Comment: You get four equation in four unknowns. Solving those, two of them are zero. Did you use Gaussian Elimination to reduce that $4 x 4$ or maybe how did you solve it?

Comment: Like to be fair with you, it was a System of Differential Equations by using Laplace transformation, so like the equation itself was: $(dx^2/dt^2) + x -y = 0$ and $(dy^2/dt^2) +y -x = 0$. Solving that I found $(s^2 +1)X -Y = -2$ and $(s^2 +1)Y -X = 1$ . After that I used the Cramer Rule to find the F(s) equation that is the following $-(2s^2 -1)/s^2(s^2+2)$

Comment: And by equaling $-2s^2-1 = A(s)(s^2+2) + B(s^2+2) + (Cs+D)s^2$ I could find values to both b and d. But when trying  to find values to A and C is just not happening

Comment: So you have $$x'' = -x + y \\ y'' = x - y$$ Is that correct?

Comment: @JorgeLucasPereiraCohen: Also, do you have ICs?

Comment: Yeah, thats correct. @Moo Like I'm a foreigner so I don't know what IC stands for actually.

Comment: Initial Conditions.

Comment: alright, $x(0)=0 ; x'(0) = -2; y(0) = 0; y'(0) =1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the system

$$\begin{align} x'' &= -x + y, x(0) = 0, x'(0) = -2 \\ y'' &= x - y, y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 1 \end{align}$$

Taking the Laplace transform of that system, we have

$$\begin{align} (s^2+1) X(s) - Y(s) &= -2 \\ - X(s) + (s^2+1) Y(s) &= 1 \end{align}$$

Multiplying the top equation by $(s^2+1)$ and adding it to the second equation

$$X(s) =  -\dfrac{2s^2 + 1}{s^2(s^2+2)} = -\frac{3}{2 \left(s^2+2\right)}-\frac{1}{2 s^2}$$

The last expansion was done using

$$-\dfrac{2s^2 + 1}{s^2(s^2+2)} = \dfrac{a}{s} + \dfrac{b}{s^2} + \dfrac{cs + d}{s^2+2}$$

This reduces to

$$-2s^2-1 = 2b + (a + c)s^3 + (b + d)s^2 + 2 a s$$

Equating terms

$$2 a = 0, 2b  = -1, b + d = -2, a + c = 0$$

This gves

$$a = c = 0, b = -\dfrac{1}{2}, d = -\dfrac{3}{2}$$

The solution should be

> $$ x(t) = \dfrac{1}{4} \left(-2 t-3 \sqrt{2} \sin \left(\sqrt{2} t\right)\right) \\ y(t)= \dfrac{1}{4} \left(-2t+3 \sqrt{2} \sin \left(\sqrt{2} t\right)\right)$$

Comment: Much thanks @Moo, I  really appreciate your help.